# SourceTree pull error

Tags: git, pull, sourcetree

I get an error when I do a `pull` to my local repository. Here is the error log:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin

git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false pull --no-commit origin master
From https://bitbucket.org/svalecillos/sistemanomastattut
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD

error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php
    config/app.php
    resources/views/auth/login.blade.php
    resources/views/auth/register.blade.php
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.



error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    resources/views/emails/password.blade.php
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting



Completed with errors, see above.
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know is in the error log you provided.

#### 1. Modified local files

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    (...)
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
```

#### 2. New local files not yet in git

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    (...)
Please move or remove them before you merge.
```

#### Suggestions

1. What I usually do in this situation is to stash my local changes, do the pull, and then apply the stash and merge any conflicts.
2. For local new / untracked files, make a backup of your file, delete it locally, and then after the pull you can compare it with the pulled file. (TIP: If you stage an untracked file before you stash, it will become part of the stashed files.)